# Limit of converging sequence of free marked groups

Tags: group-theory, geometric-group-theory

[image]

I have wrote a proof, but I think I am missing some details. Can someone please guide me through. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: A much more general result is true: if $G_1,G_2$ are marked groups and are isomorphic as groups, then there is a homeomorphism $f:V_1\to V_2$ between neighborhoods, such that $f(G_1)=G_2$ and $f(H)$ is isomorphic to $H$ (as groups) for every $H\in V_1$. This is contained in Lemma 1.3(3) of Cornulier-Guyot-Pitsch, J. Algebra 2007 https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0511714. In particular the condition "to be a limit of some kind of groups" is independent of the marking.

Comment: By the way, it is usually preferred for users to type the necessary information into their questions rather than using embedded images

Comment: Are you the author of the TeX document excerpted here?  If so, the question would benefit by standardizing the language to the level of that document.

Comment: I have no idea what you want to do in your "sketch of proof" but it sounds there's nothing to keep to get a correct proof, although the result's not deep. There is no reason to consider a subgroup $H$: it sounds like you want to prove something else. When you say "then for $i$ large enough" you invoke something; you probably don't know what. I'd rather suggest you try to understand one existing proof since they are available. In any case a proof of any theorem does not consist of writing some random statements followed by a random list of definitions preceded by "I used the below definitions."

Comment: @YCor 
Thank you for your comments. First, I would like to say that I am new to the subject of geometric group theory. I have read part of the article that you sent, and managed to write a proof, that I hope make some more sense.

Comment: which bit is causing you problems?